# What is the term for multiple simultaneous vocal lines?

Tags: voice, terminology

Is there a specific term for when a song has different vocalists singing different melodies at the same time? I know that *polyphony* refers to multiple simultaneous melodies, but is there a term specific to singing?

A song with an excellent example of what I'm asking about is Hello Seattle by Owl City [(Spotify link)](https://open.spotify.com/track/6kIpxmFQ35wgI3cK77LKbx?si=_n9zDbnaQa6jRO6BBvDMlw). At the end of the song, the chorus is sung at the same time as a verse. Another example of this is at the end of Feeling This by blink-182 [(Spotify link)](https://open.spotify.com/track/26AYR77170U49cMcXB7aRV?si=G0ZPaze2T3-w5QXP_HiHuA) (mildly not safe for work).

Comment: Probably *quodlibet* is the term you are looking for, even if not restricted to singing. See also [this question](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/23706/2600).

Comment: I always just call this "vocal harmony", but maybe that's too lowbrow or generic of a term in this context.

Comment: This is done all the time in musicals and opera.  Expand your horizons :-)

Comment: The term is “descant”.

Comment: We seem to have a battle between "polyphony" and "counterpoint".  I vote for polyphony

Comment: I think part of the problem I have with all of the answers saying that it's counterpoint is that I come from primarily working with EDM. In that pocket of the commercially-focused music world, traditional terms like counterpoint just aren't used very often. It's not necessarily wrong, but it wouldn't be the first term I'd use to communicate an idea to another producer. That's a me problem, though...

Answer (score 3):

It's certainly a polyphonic device, and 'polyphony' is another name for 'counterpoint'. 'In harmony' doesn't point out the independence of the two tunes.   A 'quodlibet' is a very specific type of humorous song. But I don't really think there's a better way of putting it than: 'The two tunes are sung together'.

Cole Porter was fond of this trick.  Nice to see some current pop artists picking it up (though, listening to the track, they've mixed the second tune so far down that it's hardly audible).

Comment: What Cole Porter songs employ this trick?

Comment: Play a Simple Melody, You're Just in Love

Answer (score 3):

Quodlibet is the term you’re looking for. From Latin for “as you please”, it’s two or more recognizable songs put together into another piece sometimes for lighthearted or humorous effect… and has been in place since the Renaissance. In fact, writing quodlibets was considered a demonstration of a Renaissance composer’s skill in counterpoint.

Examples include numerous works by Heinrich Isaac, Ludwig Senfl, Jacob Obrecht, JS Bach and many others especially in modern musical theater and even PDQ Bach—(listen to PDQ Bach’s Unbegun Symphony!). Pretty much what you might think of as today’s “mashup”.

Answer (score 2):

There is no term that specifically denotes multiple simultaneous *vocal* lines while excluding multiple simultaneous instrumental lines.  There are many terms that denote various ways in which multiple parts are played or sung at once, and some of those ways are historically or primarily vocal styles (fauxbourdon, for example).

Some of these terms (including some where there is relatively little independence among the voices) are:

- [Polyphony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyphony)
- [Counterpoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterpoint)
- [Quodlibet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quodlibet)
- [Descant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descant)
- [Organum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organum)
- [Fauxbourdon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fauxbourdon) (and variants from different languages)
- [Harmony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmony)
- [Homophony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homophony)

And to counter your assumption that "counterpoint" cannot describe a situation with two independent melodies, consider the page [Counterpoint Duet](https://allthetropes.fandom.com/wiki/Counterpoint_Duet), which describes

> A Musical trope. One character sings a song, then another character sings to the same chords but a different melody, then both sing together in counterpoint. Most often used to express arguments or show that characters have differing opinions on the same subject, though occasionally merely employed for fun.

Note the use of *counterpoint* to describe both characters singing together.

I don't suppose that a term specifically denoting vocal counterpoint would be very useful, because it is relatively efficient to add the adjective "vocal" to any of the existing terms.  On the other hand, a term denoting counterpoint of independent melodies might be useful, because describing the concept requires a phrase of at least several words.

The 11th edition of the *Encyclopædia Britannica* (1911) has an [interesting sentence on the topic](https://en.m.wikisource.org/wiki/1911_Encyclop%C3%A6dia_Britannica/Counterpoint):

> The individual audibility of the melodies is a matter of which current criticism enormously overrates the importance.

The author of that article was [Donald Francis Tovey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Tovey).

Answer (score 2):

Polyphony is the term. You can name specific genres like *round* or *madrigal* but they don't make sense to use when your examples are rock music.

This is sort of a "trick" based on presenting the two lines separately as verse and chorus and then combining them later. If the listener doesn't know anything about harmony and counterpoint it seems like something totally amazing happen, because most wouldn't expect separate sections to harmonize. But you can design music for that aim.

I think a *round* is commonly understood illustration of the mechanics. It isn't exactly the same - one melody versus song sections combined, and rock and traditional vocal music styles differ - but the musical device is the same.

Using a well known example, *Frère Jacques*, the plain melody...

[image]

...can also be written on four staves to show the melody is comprised of four short phrases that were written to harmonize with each other...

[image]

...each of the four entries can just arpeggiate the starting chord and then the phrases concatenate nicely.

Of course I don't mean to suggest Blink 182 wrote their song as a round or they consciously wrote the two melodies together and then separated them into verse and chorus. The point is just when two melodies fit the same harmonic framework then can often be played together. You can do it deliberately or stumble upon it. The end result is counterpoint and polyphony.

Answer (score 1):

I think the term you're looking for is counterpoint. See the song, "One Day More" from the musical, Les Misérables,  which is an excellent example. The song is deconstructed in this Wikipedia entry: (scroll to the "Composition" section): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Day_More

Comment: It's not counterpoint, though. I'm not talking about a main melody with a second one following along with it, I'm talking about two separate themes that have both been previously been established as major themes in the song being played simultaneously.

Comment: (Maybe I should have been more clear about that in my original question...)

Comment: @Kevin the fact that there are two melodies that are heard both separately and together does not stop it from being counterpoint.

Comment: Counterpoint does not describe multiple independent melody lines.  It is a more common term for describing homophonic harmony that is not parallel or oblique.  This is more like polophony

Comment: The "composition" section was deleted in January.  The last version to contain it may be found at https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=One_Day_More&oldid=1002463189

Comment: @user50691 counterpoint does indeed include different parts with fully independent melodies, and it certainly includes non-homophonic polyphony regardless of the degree of independence of the voices. For example, Baroque fugues are universally recognized as examples of counterpoint, they are not homophonic, and the degree of independence of the voices is low.

Comment: @Kevin in _One Day More,_ there are five or six themes that have all been previously established separately, each in a separate earlier musical number.  They are reintroduced in turn and then sung all together at the end of the number.  It's difficult to see how that fails to fulfill your criterion of "two separate themes that have both been previously been established as major themes in the song being played simultaneously."  Surely it's not because the number here is greater than two.

Answer (score 0):

I think the word you're looking for is counterpoint. It is from the latin "punctus contra punctum ",point agst point. But it is not restricted to singing.

Comment: Another word might be "difficult"  :-) .   Take listen, for example, to "Soon, Now, Later" from A Little Night Music   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=swK1ncXxZSY

Comment: It's not counterpoint, though. I'm not talking about a main melody with a second one following along with it, I'm talking about two separate themes that have both been previously been established as major themes in the song being played simultaneously.

Comment: @Kevin counterpoint may not be the word you're looking for, but two separate themes being played simultaneously is most definitely counterpoint.

Comment: Polyphony is more appropriate here.

Comment: @user50691 both words apply.