# What is the technical term for this type of singing?

Tags: voice, terminology

You have two vocalists and the first vocalist sings a verse and as he begins the second verse, your second vocalist begins to sing the first verse. The two verses are then sung together.

Comment: see also https://music.stackexchange.com/q/23706/78419

Answer (score 5):

In a ***round***, one singer (or group of singers) begin singing, and when they reach a certain point in the song, another singer (or group) enters. There can be three, four, or even more separate singers entering at various times.

A ***canon*** is a more general type of imitative piece. In a canon, parts enter one after the other, but what they sing, while similar, may not be identical. In a round, the parts of exactly identical.